# Sink vs sink down

Tags: word-choice

When you step into high fluffy snow, do you **sink down** in/into snow or you **sink** in/into snow?

**Which one is correct?**

> I stepped into snow and ended up **sinking down.**

Or

> I stepped in snow and ended **sinking** (in).

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between *sinking down* and *sinking in*? Or the difference between *sinking down* and *sinking*?

Comment: I'm asking which one is correct **sink** or **sink down**.

Comment: I think “down” is redundant but isn’t necessarily ungrammatical here. “to sink” means to slowly move down (like to the bottom of a pool or other container of liquid/non-solid substance). Like, you can’t sink any other way like “up”.

Answer (score 3):

"Sink down" is just is a little more emphatic than "sink".

They mean the same thing, and either is correct. When you add the adverb "down", it just makes you feel the "sinking" a little more dramaticallly.

> "sinking down into the snow"
>
> "sinking into the snow"
>
> "sinking down in the snow"
>
> "sinking in the snow"

All are the same, and all fine.

Answer (score 2):

All versions are correct. You can sink down in the snow. You can sink into the snow. You can sink in the snow. As Mixolydian writes, "down" may be redundant (unless you want to emphasize that you are going **down** for some reason, but it is by no means incorrect.